# How to test a File Comparator (beside Mocking the Files)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a `MyFileComparator` that uses various `java.io.File` functionality such as its methods `isDirectory()`, `getAbsolutePath()` when receiving Files to compare and i want to JUnit-test this comparator as a unit without acctually having to read/write Files on disk.

**Is there a simpler way than Mocking the two input-files if i dont want anything to be written on disk?**

Something that would spare me the whole stubbign like - for example using Mockito:

```
 File fileMock1 = Mockito.mock(File.class);
 File fileMock2 = Mockito.mock(File.class);

 Mockito.when(fileMock1.isDirectory()).thenReturn(false);
 ....
```

Comment: And dont get me wrong, i dont fear a bit of typing but considered for example things like this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/package-summary.html exist i would be a little bit surprised if i realy would have to define the entire stubbing in the "old way" for something like Files.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to write on disk (writing reading a very small file is fairly fast)

Comment: @assylias I am not sure about this since SO states i have to show my efforts and my efforts are not more than to write the question and do a 15min. websearch - which on the other hand is considered no efforts here ;)

Comment: well it looks ok to me - you show you know how to do it with Mockito. You may want to explain a bit more about why you don't want to read/write on disk and why you don't like Mockito's approach to get more targeted answers.

Comment: There is nothing like a guideline not to write to the disk - i just like the idear of doing things in memory so i dont have to care about cleaning up after testruns too much (I as well dont have to care about possible issues regarding permission to write files in remote CI infrastructure) and so on

Comment: Have you checked this? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20in%20memory%20file%20system

Comment: Very many thanks for your input, i will edit the question after a smoke-break (Thinking about your input and me not wanting something to run as it would run in a productive manner ... Mocks are probably the only way by nature to archive it ;))

Comment: @assylias hey thanks for that!! I looks like FileSystemProvider is what i will check out the next few minutes :) (And yes i am shocked too about how i seem to not be able to ask google correctly)

Comment: You mention not wanting to be writing files, but I just want to double check that you have looked into the JUnit TemporaryFolder construct using a JUnit `@Rule` annotation?

Comment: @cjstehno thanks for that advice - i indeed did not know about this feature - i however have now partially stubbed `java.io.File` as it seems to be the easiest way to dont write for the tests at all.